# How to fix error "'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command"?

Tags: python, django, pip

This is the code I've tried so far.

I tried updating it using `git clone https://github.com/django/django.git` but the error is the same:

```sh
C:\Users\HP>pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref~=3.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from django) (3.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from django) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from django) (0.3.1)

C:\Users\HP>python -m django --version
3.0.7

C:\Users\HP>django-admin
'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\HP>git clone https://github.com/django/django.git
Cloning into 'django'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 82, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (82/82), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (72/72), done.
remote: Total 458425 (delta 35), reused 19 (delta 10), pack-reused 458343 receiving objects: 100% (458425/458425), 191.37Receiving83 MiB/s
 objects: 100% (458425/458425), 192.20 MiB | 1.85 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (335466/335466), done.
Updating files: 100% (6266/6266), done.

C:\Users\HP>django-admin
'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django may not work on python3.8(latest version)
So you should use conda or virtual environment.
If you use conda, pls do like this

```
conda create --name mydjango python=3.7
conda activate mydjango
```

then you will be go into python3.7 environment instead 3.8
then Install django using this command 'pip install django'

Comment: i runed commands from pycharm terminal and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual environment where you install Django and all other packages you need for your project. then you'll know for sure django-admin will be available as expected.